# preg_replace and str_replace, can't seem to use together

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to create a BB code with a [secret] tag. The BB code "redacts" text based on the user level. However, I'm having an issue getting it to work correctly.

My current code is:

```
    $replace = array(" ", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
    $text = preg_replace('#\[secret\](.*?)\[/secret\]#si', '\1', str_replace($replace, "&#9608;", $text));
```

It outputs for the user lever:

```
█████[██████]███████████.[/██████]█████
```

Most of this is correct, however, it turned the BB tag and everything else that isn't suppose to be redacted.

I've moved the order of the preg_replace and str_replace and just cannot get it to work correctly.

Comment: That's because you're replacing the word `secret` with blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, you're replacing the tag with blocks as well, before passing it to the regular expression match. Something like this should do the trick. [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback) works almost the same as [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg-replace) but you get to use a function to say what you're replacing the string with.

```
<?php
$string = "Here is a secret: [secret]foo bar baz[/secret]";
$result = preg_replace_callback("/\[secret\](.*?)\[\/secret\]/si", function($matches) {
    return preg_replace("/[\w ]/i", "&#9608;", $matches[1]);
}, $string);
echo $result;
```

You can see the problem with your original code if you break it down to multiple steps:

```
<?php
$replace = array(" ", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
$redacted = str_replace($replace, "&#9608;", $text);
// Clearly, the string "secret" is gone by now, so the regex will never match
$text = preg_replace('#\[secret\](.*?)\[/secret\]#si', '\1', $redacted);
```

Comment: Amazing. I need to review the preg_replace_callback more, seems to be able to do magical things.